# GRMustache - mustacheBox on a subclass

Tags: swift, mustache

Getting my head around GRMustache and Swift.

If I have a class and a subclass where the parent class implements MustacheBoxable, is it possible to extend mustacheBox on the child without repeating the entire variable setup of mustacheBox?

```
class Host: MustacheBoxable {
  var name: String?
}
extension Host {
    var mustacheBox: MustacheBox {
      return Box([
         "name": self.name
      ])
    }
}

class TopGearHost: Host {
  var drives_slowly: Bool = false
}
extension Host {
    var mustacheBox: MustacheBox {
      //how would I go about NOT doing this?
      return Box([
          "name": self.name,  // don't want to repeat this guy
          "drives_slowly": self.drives_slowly
      ])
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any tips / guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think this is exactly elegant, I did figure out a way to approach this.

- Create variable ("boxedValues") for exporting properties from parent class

  mustacheBox on parent returns the boxed variable

  Child class can then access the parent ("boxedValues") variable and add values

  Implementation of mustacheBox just continues to work for child class

```
class Host: MustacheBoxable {
    var name: String?
}
extension Host {
    var boxedValues: [String:MustacheBox] {
        return [ "name" : self.name ]
    }
    var mustacheBox: MustacheBox {
        return Box(boxedValues)
    }
}
class TopGearHost: Host {
    var drives_slowly: Bool = false
}
extension Host {
    override var boxedValues: [String:MustacheBox] {
        var vals = super.boxedValues
        vals["drives_slowly"] = Box(self.drives_slowly)
        return vals
    }
}
```